# jQuery type HTMLElement not identified

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to get the kind of HTML tag from a string.

```
console.info("type: "+jQuery.type(txt));
if ( jQuery.type(txt) !== "object HTMLElement" ) {
    console.info("-> "+txt);
```

the output is for both logs are:

```
type: object
-> [object HTMLElement]
```

Is there any way to Identify **HTMLElement** as a type of object?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The first `console.log` clearly shows the answer to your question: *"Is there any way to Identify HTMLElement as a type of object?"*, which is yes because `jQuery.type(txt)` gives back `object`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It just shows that it's an object and in the second log, HTMLElement object, which its diferent. I need to identify what kind of object is.

Comment: In your question you are asking to identity `HTMLElement` as a type of `object`, which is what`jQuery.type` is doing. So what's the issue here? I think you are implying the opposite, that you don't want to identity `HTMLElement` as an `object`, and rather a different type.

Comment: Are you looking for `obj instanceof HTMLElement`?

Comment: @Xufox maybe, let me try it.

Comment: So you're trying to get the tag name? i.e. you want your code to return `<a>`, `<div>`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, try it :

```
let HTMLText = '<b>example</b>'
let tempElem =  document.createElement('div');
tempElem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',HTMLText);
console.log(tempElem.firstChild.nodeType);
```

Node type you can get from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

If nodetype === 3 , this  is a text, if === 1  --- is a tag.
If your HTMl has lot of tags, use loop for all childNodes of tempElem